# Test environment does not copy my files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I use VS2010. In my test project I have a folder named "MessageInstances" and in that folder there is a subfolder "GET_ACTIVITY", inside that folder there are xml files.

When I run a test, these files should be copied accordingly to the out assembly dir, i.e. if `Out` is the folder where my test project output is copied then `Out\MessageInstances\GET_ACTIVITY\` folder should be filled with my xml files.

I tried different settings with `*.testsettings` file, tried running the test from Resharper unit test runner and from VS', but neither copied the files into the right folder. Also I played with `DeploymentItem` attribute and still no success.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DeploymentItem attribute will only work if **Build Action** on the item is set to **Content** and the **Copy to Output Directory** is set to **Copy if Newer** or **Copy always**. Additionally, if your tests are running with a testsettings file you need to enable Deployment in the settings. Make sure you are editing the active test run config in case you have mutiple.

Your DeploymentItem should be defined as follows:

```
[DeploymentItem("MessageInstances\\GET_ACTIVITY\\", "MessageInstances\\GET_ACTIVITY")]
```

Or using '@' instead of '\\'

```
[DeploymentItem(@"MessageInstances\GET_ACTIVITY\", @"MessageInstances\GET_ACTIVITY")]
```

i.e. you need to specify the output directory, otherwise the files will be copied to the Out directory of your test run.

Comment: It turned out that every time I add a new folder to be deployed, I have to restart VS. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you bring up the properties of the files in the solution explorer, verify that the files are set to `Build Action: Content` and `Copy to output director: Always`

Answer (score 0):

Some my colleagues experienced the similar problem with ReSharper MS test runner. 
The bug was specific for ReSharper 7.1 and has been fixed in current 7.1.1.

See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-335233#tab=Comment

Answer (score 0):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) , you can also try this if this helps,

To select files or folders to deploy, in run configuration

In Solution Explorer, under Solution Items, double-click the run configuration file that you want to edit.

A dialog box that has a name such as .testrunconfig appears.
Click Deployment.

Under Additional files or directories to deploy, specify additional files or folders to be copied.

To do this, click Add file to select files; this opens the Add Deployment Files dialog box.

You can also click Add Directory to select folders by using the Add Deployment Directory dialog box.

In the .testrunconfig dialog box, click Save and then click OK.

These deployment items will be copied to the deployment folder whenever this run configuration file is active.

Hope this will help.