# VSTS Visual Studio Test Task does not always copy app.config

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-test-runner

I am using Visual Studio Team Service with the new scriptable Build system. There is a Visual Studio Test Task. The problem I am facing is, that the app.configs of a unit-test project are not always deployed into the TestResult...\Out folder. But this files contain important settings (we are using CSLA). What is interesting, is that for some test projects the files get copied. I checked the property window but there is no difference. We are using VS2015.

Comment: You may need to specify DeploymentItem as described in [Test environment does not copy my files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9096884)

Comment: I am going now a complete different way. Wrote my own script to deploy all config files necessary for the test. I still doesn't make sense to me that it is working locally on every developer machine when i run the tests from Visual Studio.